# Picard theorem for functions which are locally lipschitz

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I am a bit confused by the 4th bullet point. Is it just saying that $f$ is evaluated at points of $U$ for the time interval $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The growth of trajectories is restricted by $M$. Thus any trajectory, if it exists, will satisfy $$|x(t)-x_0|\le M·|t|$$ as long as it stays in $U$ (which is redundant, since no trajectory can leave the domain of definition of $f$).

Now $h$ gets chosen in such a way that the double cone 
$$
\{(t,y):|t|\le h,\;|y-x_0|\le M·|t|\}
\subset
\{(t,y):|t|\le h,\;|y-x_0|\le M·h\}
$$ 
is still inside the domain $U$.

---

The restriction $h\le\frac1{2K}$ comes from the lazy option of using the standard supremum norm on the space of continuous functions. Using the problem-adapted norm 
$$
\|x\|_K=\sup_{|t|<h}e^{-2K·|t|}·\|x(t)\|
$$
the Picard iteration is contractive for even for the maximum $h$ that fits the double cone inside $U$.