# Uniqueness of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> 3. Solve the differential equation $\dot x=1+x^2$, with $x(0) = x_0$. Why can you be certain that the solution is unique? Show that for all values of $x_0$ the solution goes to infinity in finite time, both forwards and backwards.

I have found the solution to be $x(t)=\tan(t+\arctan x_0)$. How would I go about proving uniqueness? Is the solution the entire graph of $\tan(t+\arctan x_0)$ or only the tan wave which is defined on the interval (when $\arctan(x_0)>0$):

$$-\frac{\pi}2-\arctan x_0<t<\frac{\pi}2-\arctan x_0   $$

i.e the tan wave with domain containing $t=0$ so that the tan wave intersects the $x$ axis at $x_0$

Comment: A little strange that you should ask this, in view of [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1233066/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniqueness follows from the general Picard-Lindelöf (or if you prefer, Cauchy-Lipschitz) [existence and uniqueness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for differential equations.

Since the solution blows up as $t + \arctan(x_0)$ approaches $\pm \pi/2$, the solution is only on the interval $-\pi/2 < t +  \arctan(x_0) < \pi/2$.

Comment: Ok so $f(x)=1+x^2$ is lipschitz on the interval $-\pi/2 < t +  \arctan(x_0) < \pi/2$. Is the reason the solution only exists on $-\pi/2 < t +  \arctan(x_0) < \pi/2$ because $x$ must be continuous as it is differentiable?

Comment: $f(t,x) = 1 + x^2$ is **locally** Lipschitz in $x$, not globally.  Yes, that is the reason.

Comment: For it to be locally lipschitz would we not require there to be a $K>0$ st |$x+y$|$\leq K$ $\forall x,y$. However since $x,y \in (-\infty,\infty)$; for any  $K>0$ I can pick $x,y$ st |$x+y$|$>K$?

Comment: Also [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Picard%27s_Existence_Theorem) version of the existence theorem requires $f$ to be bounded and yet it is not in this case?

Comment: "Locally" in this case because in any bounded rectangle $a \le t \le b$, $c \le x \le d$ it's Lipschitz.  Similarly it's bounded in any bounded rectangle, which is all you really need.